# How to delete the dynamically created image in the following code?

Tags: jquery

This is where I dynamically create an image:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
                var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
                // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    // Only process image files.
                    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    fileNames.push(f.name);
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    // Closure to capture the file information.
                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                            // Render thumbnail.
                            var span = document.createElement('span');
                            span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" id="',escape(theFile.name),'" src="',e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><input class="delete" type="button" value="delete" name="',escape(theFile.name),'"/>'].join('');
                            document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                        };
                    })(f);
                    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                }
```

And this is where I want to delete the image when I press the button:

```
$('#list').on("click",".delete",function(e){
                $(e.target).remove();

            });
```

Answer (score 2):

*as image is before the button you are clicking*

```
$('#list').on("click",".delete",function(e){
   $(this).prev('img').remove();
});
```

Comment: can also reference on the `<img>` id to execute the `remove()` function.

Comment: As OP is using `.delete` to attach event handler  - The image can be referenced with `$(this)` . alternatively if he wan't to remove with id  _as you said_ You need to get the ID of the image first `$(this).prev('img').attr('id');`